# Blur the phone wallpaper with all app icons and use that as app background?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm thinking this is not possible but I'm just making sure.

What I want to do is to blur the image of the background with the wallpaper and all the app icons and have that as the background to my app, just like with the control center. I'm thinking somehow it will need to take a screenshot of the background before the app environment is launched and that's what makes me think that this is not possible

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with public API.

---

To elaborate a bit more, you have the private `UIApplicationIsOpaque` plist value which you can set to NO, and then your application's background will be the user's wallpaper (like in Safari and Passbook). Some apps have been uploaded in the past with this property hidden, but since, they have been updated to remove it, likely by request of Apple.

`UIApplicationIsOpaque` does not include the SpringBoard icons. If you would like to capture that one, you would need to use other private API. Not sure it is even possible without Jailbreak.